# Recovering terraform state after accidentally deletion and lock

Tags: terraform

I previously had my terraform.tfstate locally and accidentally deleted it. I've now moved it to gitlab's http backend and am trying to import my resources to get it back.

I'm running

```
terraform import "module.mymodule.acl" acl-xxx123
```

but getting the error

```
 Error: Error acquiring the state lock
│
│ Error message: Unexpected HTTP response code 308
│
│ Terraform acquires a state lock to protect the state from being written
│ by multiple users at the same time. Please resolve the issue above and try
│ again. For most commands, you can disable locking with the "-lock=false"
│ flag, but this is not recommended
```

I can't see a way of forcing an unlock without a lock ID. Is there a way to force unlock this to recover the state?